# recurring scheduler in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, dagger-2, android-mvp

I wanna remove old stuff from the ListView, so I defined recurring scheduler as a handler in the Activity.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doSomethingOnRecyclerView();
        handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 2000);
    }
};
handler.post(runnableCode);
```

It works, however, I'm refactoring the app to use RxJava, mvp and dagger. How to do recurring scheduler in RxJava?
Where to keep it in MVP architecture, in presenter?

Comment: `Observable.interval()`˙?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have the handler live in the presenter class and call the appropriate view methods at each interval. With RX you can have an emitter (or flowable?) that fires every x seconds. This will accomplish the same thing that you have in your code.

Be sure to wire up the scheduler to the presenter's lifecycle